# how can i make activity for player vs ai for xo game in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

i'm trying to make xo game single player vs ai , multi player player vs player , and online mode.
can someone help me for this please!

```
import android.content.Intent
    import android.os.Bundle
    import android.view.View
    import android.widget.TextView
    import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
    import androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
    import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat
    
    class TwoPlayers : AppCompatActivity() {
    
        private var playerone = ArrayList<Int>()
        private var playertwo = ArrayList<Int>()
        private lateinit var xwinstxt: TextView
        private lateinit var owinstxt: TextView
        var activeplayer = 1
        var attemptsCount = 9
    
        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_two_players)
    
            xwinstxt = findViewById(R.id.xwinstxt)
            owinstxt = findViewById(R.id.owinstxt)
    
            val intent = intent
    
            val nameone = intent.getStringExtra("firstplayername")
            val nametwo = intent.getStringExtra("secondplayername")
            xwinstxt.text = nameone
            owinstxt.text = nametwo
    
        }
    
        fun buttonClicked(view: View) {
            val buttonClicked = view as AppCompatButton
            var num = 0
            when (buttonClicked.id) {
                R.id.button1 -> num = 1
                R.id.button2 -> num = 2
                R.id.button3 -> num = 3
                R.id.button4 -> num = 4
                R.id.button5 -> num = 5
                R.id.button6 -> num = 6
                R.id.button7 -> num = 7
                R.id.button8 -> num = 8
                R.id.button9 -> num = 9
            }
            playGame(num, buttonClicked)
        }
    
        private fun playGame(num: Int, buttonClicked: AppCompatButton) {
            attemptsCount -= 1
            if (activeplayer == 1) {
                buttonClicked.background = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.x_icon)
                playerone.add(num)
                activeplayer = 2
            } else {
                buttonClicked.background = ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.o_icon)
                playertwo.add(num)
                activeplayer = 1
            }
            buttonClicked.isEnabled = false
            checkwinner()
        }
    
        private fun checkwinner() {
            var winner = -1
            if (attemptsCount == 0) {
                val intent = Intent(this, WinnerPage::class.java)
                WinnerPage.winnerPlayertxt = "Draw Game !"
                startActivity(intent)
                finish()
            }

        if (playerone.contains(1) && playerone.contains(2) && playerone.contains(3)) winner = 1
        if (playertwo.contains(1) && playertwo.contains(2) && playertwo.contains(3)) winner = 2

        if (playerone.contains(4) && playerone.contains(5) && playerone.contains(6)) winner = 1
        if (playertwo.contains(4) && playertwo.contains(5) && playertwo.contains(6)) winner = 2

        if (playerone.contains(7) && playerone.contains(8) && playerone.contains(9)) winner = 1
        if (playertwo.contains(7) && playertwo.contains(8) && playertwo.contains(9)) winner = 2

        if (playerone.contains(1) && playerone.contains(4) && playerone.contains(7)) winner = 1
        if (playertwo.contains(1) && playertwo.contains(4) && playertwo.contains(7)) winner = 2

        if (playerone.contains(2) && playerone.contains(5) && playerone.contains(8)) winner = 1
        if (playertwo.contains(2) && playertwo.contains(5) && playertwo.contains(8)) winner = 2

        if (playerone.contains(3) && playerone.contains(6) && playerone.contains(9)) winner = 1
        if (playertwo.contains(3) && playertwo.contains(6) && playertwo.contains(9)) winner = 2

        if (playerone.contains(1) && playerone.contains(5) && playerone.contains(9)) winner = 1
        if (playertwo.contains(1) && playertwo.contains(5) && playertwo.contains(9)) winner = 2

        if (playerone.contains(3) && playerone.contains(5) && playerone.contains(7)) winner = 1
        if (playertwo.contains(3) && playertwo.contains(5) && playertwo.contains(7)) winner = 2

        if (winner == 1) {
            val intent = Intent(this, WinnerPage::class.java)
            WinnerPage.winnerPlayertxt = "X Wins"
            startActivity(intent)
            finish()
        }
        if (winner == 2) {
            val intent = Intent(this, WinnerPage::class.java)
            WinnerPage.winnerPlayertxt = "O Wins"
            startActivity(intent)
            finish()
        }
    }
}
```

i made xo game for multiplayer how can i make xo game for single player vs ai ?
please someone help me what i need to make for ai , i'm kotlin developer.
just tell me what i need to do because i don't know what i need to make here what is the function should be created for random move for ai.

Answer (score 0):

a good approach i did to my own TicTacToe(XO) game is I store all my board in an array of size 9 one for each playing space in the board and then for exemple if the player starts first the i check what available spaces are store them in an array and then make a random movement.
This will work but if you want a more intelligent Ai you can try to add one step more and that is after you check for available spaces then you check what are the spaces that the player took for himself and then if the next move of the player could mean that he will when for exemple if the array returned(X,X, ,O,X,O, , , ) that means if the player puts an X in the index 2 he will when but you make your ai put it there to prevent him from winning.
so you have to check for all the posibile moves the player could do to win which by the way are just 8 posibilities.
you can use something like this:

```
object GameUtils {
    const val PLAYER_X = "X" //player 1
    const val PLAYER_O = "O" //player 2 or computer

    /**
     * Determine if the board is full
     * */
    fun isBoardFull(board: ArrayList<String>): Boolean {
        for (i in board) {
            if (i != PLAYER_X && i != PLAYER_O) return false
        }
        return true
    }

    /**
     * Makes a copy of the board
     * */
    fun copyBoard(board: ArrayList<String>): ArrayList<String> {
        val newBoard = arrayListOf("", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "")
        for (i in 0 until board.count()) {
            newBoard[i] = board[i]
        }
        return newBoard
    }

    /**
     * Choose a random move
     * */
    fun chooseRandomMove(board: ArrayList<String>, moves: ArrayList<Int>): Int {
        val possibleMoves = arrayListOf<Int>()

        for (i in moves) {
            if (board[i] == "") possibleMoves.add(i)
        }

        return if (possibleMoves.isEmpty()) {
            -1
        } else {
            val index = Random().nextInt(possibleMoves.count())
            possibleMoves[index]
        }
    }

    /**
     * Chooses a random move for the computer based on the order of
     * priority to make the computer win. It mimics AI
     * */
    fun computerMove(board: ArrayList<String>): Int {
        //check if computer can win in this move
        for (i in 0 until board.count()) {
            val copy = copyBoard(board)
            if (copy[i] == "") copy[i] = PLAYER_O

            //check for win
            if (isGameWon(copy, PLAYER_O)) return i
        }


        //check if player could win in the next move
        for (i in 0 until board.count()) {
            val copy = copyBoard(board)
            if (copy[i] == "") copy[i] = PLAYER_X

            if (isGameWon(copy, PLAYER_X)) return i
        }

        //try to make corners if it is free
        val move = chooseRandomMove(board, arrayListOf(0, 2, 6, 8))
        if (move != -1) return move

        //try to take center if it is free
        if (board[4] == "") return 4

        //finally try to make the sides
        return chooseRandomMove(board, arrayListOf(1, 3, 5, 7))
    }


    /**
     * Determines if the game is won
     * */
    fun isGameWon(board: ArrayList<String>, player: String): Boolean =
        //check rows
        if (board[0] == player && board[1] == player && board[2] == player) true
        else if (board[3] == player && board[4] == player && board[5] == player) true
        else if (board[6] == player && board[7] == player && board[8] == player) true

        //check columns
        else if (board[0] == player && board[3] == player && board[6] == player) true
        else if (board[1] == player && board[4] == player && board[7] == player) true
        else if (board[2] == player && board[5] == player && board[8] == player) true

        //check diagonals
        else if (board[2] == player && board[4] == player && board[6] == player) true
        else board[0] == player && board[4] == player && board[8] == player

    /**
     * Returns a readable game won text
     * */
    fun gameResult(board: ArrayList<String>, singleMode: Boolean): String {
        when {
            isGameWon(board, PLAYER_X) -> return "${if (singleMode) "YOU" else "PLAYER X"} Won"
            isGameWon(board, PLAYER_O) -> return "${if (singleMode) "COMPUTER" else "PLAYER O"} Won"
            isBoardFull(board) -> return "It is Tie"
        }
        return "Tie"
    }
}
```

Credits to the code above to [Jerry Hanks Okafor](https://github.com/jerryOkafor/TicTacToe/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/jerryokafor/tictactoe/engine/GameUtils.kt)